# How to send more attributes in SAML response along with email Id

Tags: adfs2.0, openam

I am doing login to ADFS using fedlet created using openam. In fedlet i am getting saml response from ADFS in which I get only email address but I want other attributes like role,user name,user status,password .How I do get this attributes in my fedlet application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you took the sp.xml fedlet file and imported it into ADFS as a RP trust?

All you need to do is add some claims rules to the RP using the "Send LDAP Attributes as Claims" and then select the AD attributes you want to include in the SAML response.